# right syntax to use near '?'

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc, prepared-statement

I have a Java-code:

```
String searchPerson = "select * from persons where surname like ? and name like ?";
//connect to DB
PreparedStatement statement = connect.prepareStatement(searchPerson);
statement.setString(1,"%"+ surname + "%");
statement.setString(2, "%" + name + "%");
ResultSet resultPerson = statement.executeQuery(searchPerson);
//..code
```

Then I have SQLException:

> you have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?'

Comment: @AdamYost: no he doesn't, that's the whole point of ? placeholder

Comment: than I have an error to set String:
`code`
statement.setString(1,"%"+ surname + "%");
statement.setString(2, "%" + name + "%");
`code`

Comment: I guess this is one of mysql bugs. Change you statement to `like '%' || ? || '%'` and use `.setString(1, surname)` and it should work

Comment: @mvp than I have: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '? || '%''

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should execute the `PrepareStatement` with no parameters as follows:

```
statement.executeQuery()
```

Calling `executeQuery` with a `String` parameter will execute the provided query as is (without the bound parameters).

Answer (score 1):

```
ResultSet resultPerson = statement.executeQuery(searchPerson);
```

should be

```
ResultSet resultPerson = statement.executeQuery();
```

Answer (score -2):

Try with `statement.setString(1,"'%"+ surname + "%'");`

Comment: You don't need single quotes here.