# Right syntax to use near '?' ORDER BY

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

```php
$array = array();
$stmt = $connection->prepare("SELECT * 
                              FROM ?
                              ORDER BY `score` DESC");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $name);
$stmt->execute();
$data = $stmt->get_result();

while($row = $data->fetch_assoc()){
    array_push($array, $row);
}
```

> Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '? ORDER BY `score` DESC' at line 2 in...

target_leaderboard is the database I connect to in my separate "connection.php" file I include at the top of this php page.

I am trying to prevent SQL-Injection attacks by using the method described in [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) but I'm not sure how to solve this error.

I've looked at [right syntax to use near '?'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24917917/right-syntax-to-use-near) but I think my issue is different.

Comment: Identifiers can't be bound parameters.

Comment: Oh. Do I simply put $name, or would that be at risk to SQL-INJECTION?

Comment: ^^  You need something more like `SELECT *  FROM $database WHERE field = ? ORDER BY \`score\` DESC`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You intent is OK. However, databases do not support passing table names as variables; keep in mind that the query planner needs to be able to *prepare* the statement (that is, generate its execution plan) by looking at the parameterized query only (without seeing the parameters). Parameters are meant to pass literal values to the query.

So you are left with performing the validation in your application first (against a fixed list of values, or by querying `information_schema.tables`), and then concatenating the table name in your query:

```
$stmt = $connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM `$name` ORDER BY `score` DESC");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $name);
$stmt->execute();
```